# RestFB - Delete post in group on facebook

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

When trying to delete a post using RestFB I can easily delete a post I made on my timeline but I can't delete one made into a group. This is the code I'm using:

```
Boolean deleted = fbClient.deleteObject(id);
System.out.println("Deleted object? " + deleted);
```

I am getting the post id from the posting method so I'm sure it's the right id. The code sets the deleted boolean to true but the post doesn't get deleted and stays in the group.
Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: Try to delete a post in a group with the graph api explorer. If this is working there may be a bug in restfb...

Comment: I've already done that with the same result. Returns as if the deletion succeeded but the post remains.

Comment: so this is an Facebook issue. If you're sure this should work open a bug in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/